# How can I enforce implementation of string/byte[] serialization methods in a generic WebSocket client abstraction in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a WebSocket client abstraction in C# using the [Websocket.Client](https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client) library. I want each derived class to handle either string or byte[] serialization, but not both.

It works fine but the code looks terrible. By the way, the method definition `protected void Send(object request)` should remain the same because I want to be able to pass anything in there.

```cs
public interface ICommunicator : IWebsocketClient
{
}

public sealed class Communicator : WebsocketClient, ICommunicator
{
    public Communicator(Uri url, Func<ClientWebSocket>? clientFactory = null) : base(url, clientFactory)
    {
    }

    public Communicator(Uri url, Func<Uri, CancellationToken, Task<WebSocket>> connectionFactory) : base(url, connectionFactory)
    {
    }
}

public readonly struct SerializedMessage
{
    public SerializedMessage(string? text, byte[]? binary)
    {
        Text = text;
        Binary = binary;
    }

    public string? Text { get; }
    public byte[]? Binary { get; }
}

public abstract class BaseWebSocketClient<TLogger, TMessage> : IDisposable
    where TLogger : BaseWebSocketClient<TLogger, TMessage>
{
    protected readonly ILogger<TLogger> Logger;

    private readonly ICommunicator _communicator;

    protected BaseWebSocketClient(ICommunicator communicator, ILoggerFactory? loggerFactory = null)
    {
        Logger = (loggerFactory ?? NullLoggerFactory.Instance).CreateLogger<TLogger>();
        _communicator = communicator;

        _reconnectionSubscription = communicator.ReconnectionHappened
            .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
            .SubscribeSafelyAsync(OnReconnectionAsync, Logger);

        _messageReceivedSubscription = communicator.MessageReceived
            .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
            .SubscribeSafelyAsync(OnMessageReceivedAsync, Logger);
    }

    protected void Send(object request)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(request);

        var serializedMessage = Serialize(request);

        if (serializedMessage.Text != null && serializedMessage.Binary != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You can either serialize to text or binary but not both.");
        }

        switch (serializedMessage)
        {
            case { Text.Length: > 0 }:
                _communicator.Send(serializedMessage.Text);
                break;

            case { Binary.Length: > 0 }:
                _communicator.Send(serializedMessage.Binary);
                break;

            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Serialized message must contain either text or binary data.");
        }
    }

    protected abstract SerializedMessage Serialize(object request);
}

// gRPC client (Google.Protobuf)
public class CqgWebSocketClient : BaseWebSocketClient<CqgWebSocketClient, ServerMsg>
{
    protected override SerializedMessage Serialize(object request)
    {
        if (request is not IMessage message)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Request object does not implement {nameof(IMessage)}", nameof(request));
        }

        return new SerializedMessage(null, message.ToByteArray());
    }
}

public class DeribitWebSocketClient : BaseWebSocketClient<DeribitWebSocketClient, JsonElement>
{
    protected override SerializedMessage Serialize(object request)
    {
        if (request is string stringRequest)
        {
            // If the request is already a string, use it directly
            return new SerializedMessage(stringRequest, null);
        }

        // Otherwise, serialize the request object into a JSON string
        return new SerializedMessage(JsonSerializer.Serialize(request), null);
    }
}
```

### My unsuccessful attempt

```cs
public interface ISerializationMethod { }

public interface IStringSerializable : ISerializationMethod
{
    string SerializeToString(object request);
}

public interface IBinarySerializable : ISerializationMethod
{
    byte[] SerializeToBinary(object request);
}

public abstract class BaseWebSocketClient<TLogger, TMessage, TSerializationMethod> : IDisposable
    where TLogger : BaseWebSocketClient<TLogger, TMessage, TSerializationMethod>
    where TSerializationMethod : class, ISerializationMethod
{
    protected void Send(object request)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(request);

        if (this is IStringSerializable stringSerializable)
        {
            var message = stringSerializable.SerializeToString(request);
            _communicator.Send(message);
        }
        else if (this is IBinarySerializable binarySerializable)
        {
            var data = binarySerializable.SerializeToBinary(request);
            _communicator.Send(data);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Client must implement either IStringSerializable or IBinarySerializable.");
        }
    }
}

public class CqgWebSocketClient : BaseWebSocketClient<CqgWebSocketClient, ServerMsg, IBinarySerializable>
{
    // I want to enforce implementation of SerializeToBinary here.
}

public class DeribitWebSocketClient : BaseWebSocketClient<DeribitWebSocketClient, JsonElement, IStringSerializable>
{
    // I want to enforce implementation of SerializeToString here.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> either string or byte[] serialization, but not both

This sounds like a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), or variant, i.e. a object that can have one of a fixed set of types. Often called `Either` when implemented, ([first google hit on github](https://gist.github.com/jonfunkhouser/de0d9f5dc2dd5e6dd8cb)).

You would typically either check the actual type and call different methods, or let the either class do it for you, something like `message.Case(HandleStringMessage, HandleBinaryMessage)`